# Are there opendatasets of English terms describing nationalities, ethnicities?

Tags: data-request, language, english, nlp

Say one needs to parse text for any mention of nationality or ethnicity, or otherwise use these terms in the course of an NLP project. Is there a comprehensive resource of English words describing these? The interest is in both adjectives and nouns, e.g. "Turkish" and "Turk."

Comment: @aeroNotAuto The same thought crossed my mind, and I can see reasons for it fitting in either. In the end I put it here because the focus was on a tool to be used in analysis, irrespective of whether that tool is an open dataset. Anyways, I leave it up to the mods. :)

Answer (score 6):

Both are available in the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/). Nationality names, both noun and adjective, for world countries are available [here](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2110.html); ethnicities, listed by country, [here](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2075.html). (This may not be *historically* comprehensive.)

The promised tabular data referenced in the 'Technical' section of the [FAQ](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/docs/faqs.html) doesn't seem to exist for this dataset: Light scraping required.

Answer (score 5):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is a (free) semantic database of the English language. You could [query](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) for example the complete hyponym tree of the term "inhabitant". Depending on your application, it could be a disadvantage that WordNet also contains historical ethnicities or nationalities.

For language names, an excellent database is [Glottolog.](http://glottolog.org)

Once I compiled a dictionary of 200 language names as a csv file in [this GitHub repository.](https://github.com/SuzanaK/dictionary_of_language_names)

Comment: Upvoted for glottolog. Downvoted for WordNet - how exactly do you get to a hyponym tree?

Comment: There are many excellent interfaces to WordNet, for example [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and [Nodebox Linguistics](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics).